# How to limit Visitor group to just edit one view in the list and not see the other view

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list-view, custom-list, view

I have a SharePoint list with 2 views. One is the All items view and the other is a custom view. There is a SharePoint group in the Site named "Visitors". I want this group to just have edit access to the custom view and no access (I.e not to see) to All items view. 
How can this be achieved? Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by applying target audience to the list view web part. Following are the steps.

1. Switch to Classic Experience.
2. Edit the `AllItems.aspx` page.
3. Edit the List View Web part and in the settings pan in the right hand side, look for target audience.
4. Set the group other than `Visitor` (Owners or any other) and save the settings.

Do the same steps for you custom view. Only difference here will be that you need to enter `Visitors` group in the target audience.

Comment: Thank you, this Worked!

Answer (score 1):

And for sure, make sure that the Visitor Group has no right to make new views.

Comment: Yes. That is taken care of. Thank you